# Source of Hirsch Vayikra 23:15

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashas-emor, samson-raphael-hirsch

I'm looking for a english translation of Hirsch his full commentary on [VaYikra 23:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0323.htm#15). Does anyone knows where i could find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been two published versions of English translations of R' Hirsch's commentary on the Torah:

- [R' Isaac Levy's translation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0910818126), published by Judaica Press, is out of print now, but can be found in many libraries and homes.
- [Daniel Haberman's translation](http://www.feldheim.com/authors/hirsch-rabbi-samson-raphael/the-hirsch-chumash.html), published by Feldheim, was released more recently and is in print.